# Number of functions $\{ f: [k] \rightarrow[n] :|f([k])|=m \}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If we have $k,\;n,\;m\in\mathbb{N}: m\leq n$, how to determine $|\{ f: [k] \rightarrow[n] :|f([k])|=m \}|$.
Were we have $ [n]:=\{1,2,...,n\}.$

So firstly, there should be a $ \binom{n}{m} $ ways to choose a subset of $[n]$ with the cardinality $m$.

But this is where I am stuck, I would appreciate any help for further calcualtion.

Comment: The relevant notion here is [Sterling numbers of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264799/calculating-the-total-number-of-surjective-functions)

Comment: Stirling actually

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am aware of that, but not sure how to calculate it.

Comment: the wikipedia page is a good place to start https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: You can also use an inclusion-exclusion argument; the last part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978944/finding-a-closed-form-expression-for-the-recurrence-relation-an-k1-k1n/3979186#3979186) does it for the case $m=n$, and you already know how to modify that result.